# PHP - Get Meta Information by EmbedURL

Tags: metadata, php-7

How I will get meta information specified by `EmbedURL`? I have tried `get_meta_tags('MY_VIDEO_URL')`. But it returns nothing.

## **MY HTML:**

```
<!--Video 1-->
        <div class="embed-responsive-item" itemprop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
                                      <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="" loop="">
                            <source src="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL">
                          </video>
                         <meta itemprop="name" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="duration" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="THUMBNAIL_URL">
                         <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL">
                          <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z">
            </div>
<!--Video 2-->
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" onclick="loadYoutubeVideoThroughYTApi(this)" data-src-id="player-1" data-yut-var="YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID">
                <meta itemprop="description" content="META_DESCRIPTION_2">
                <meta itemprop="duration" content="PT1M13S">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="META_TITLE_2">
                <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg">
               <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID">
              <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2019-02-04T11:00:43.000Z">
            </div>
<!--Video 3-->
    <div class="embed-responsive-item" itemprop="video" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
                                      <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls="" loop="">
                            <source src="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2">
                          </video>
                         <meta itemprop="name" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="duration" content="">
                         <meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="THUMBNAIL_URL_2">
                         <meta itemprop="embedURL" content="INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2">
                          <meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z">
            </div>
```

As you can see the html contains three different videos with three different meta properties. So the result array should be look like this

## **Desired Output:**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [url] => INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL
                [meta_name] => NULL
                [meta_description] => NULL // as you can see no meta tags for description
                [meta_duration] => NULL
                [meta_thumbnail] => THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID
                [meta_name] => META_TITLE_2
                [meta_description] => META_DESCRIPTION_2
                [meta_duration] => PT1M13S
                [meta_thumbnail] => https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID/maxresdefault.jpg
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [url] => INTERNAL_VIDEO_URL_2
                [meta_name] => NULL
                [meta_description] => NULL // as you can see no meta tags for description
                [meta_duration] => NULL
                [meta_thumbnail] => THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_URL_2
                [upload_date] => 2021-03-27T04:10:1600Z
            )
    )
```

How will I get the set of array like this?

Comment: Just a casual FYI; According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) `get_meta_tags` requires a file name, not the string you want it to parse. So that's why that didn't do anything for you.

Comment: So, how will I get my desired output? Please help

Comment: @AlainDoe I have modified the code based on your solution and I got my desired output.

Comment: Happy to hear that you managed to find a solution for your problem  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many research I have come up with a solution that gives my desired output.

```
<?php
function load_my_custom_attributes_from_meta_tags( $string )
{
    
    $htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
    $errorBuffer = libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $htmlDom->loadHTML($string);
    libxml_clear_errors();
    libxml_use_internal_errors( $errorBuffer  );
    
    $result = Array(
            "url" => NULL,
            "meta_name" => NULL,
            "meta_description" => NULL,
            "meta_duration" => NULL,
            "meta_thumbnail" => NULL,
            "upload_date" => NULL
    );
    
    $arrayKeyMap = Array( 
        "embedURL"=>"url",
        "name"=>"meta_name",
        "description"=>"meta_description",
        "thumbnailURL"=>"meta_thumbnail",
        "duration"=>"meta_duration",
        "uploadDate"=>"upload_date"
    );
    
    $main_array = array();
    foreach ($htmlDom->getElementsByTagName("meta") as $tag) {
        $temp = Array();
        foreach ( $tag->attributes as $attribute ) {
            $temp[ $attribute->nodeName ] = $attribute->nodeValue;
        }
        if ( array_key_exists( "itemprop" , $temp ) && array_key_exists( "content" , $temp )  && array_key_exists( $temp["itemprop"] , $arrayKeyMap ) ) {
            $result[ $arrayKeyMap[ $temp["itemprop"] ] ] = $temp["content"] === "" ? NULL : $temp["content"];
            
        }
    }
    
    return $result;
}


$file_contents = file_get_contents('PAGE_URL');
preg_match_all('/<div class=\"embed-responsive\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file_contents,$matches);
$all_meta_properties = $matches[0];
$meta_array = array();
foreach($all_meta_properties as $video_meta) {
    $meta_array[] = load_my_custom_attributes_from_meta_tags($video_meta);
}
print_r($meta_array);
?>
```